# JPA Buddy does not generate versionned migration but does like my database was empty

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, flyway, jpa-buddy

I use the JPA Buddy plugin in the Intellij IDEA editor. My project is a SpringBoot application, and my database is a postgresql database.

I usually use this plugin to be able to quickly generate my SQL migrations when my data model changes in my code. When I initiated my project, I was able to correctly generate and then automatically execute the SQL script to create the database tables.

However, I now need to evolve my entities. So I changed my code to suit my needs. However, when I use JPA Buddy again, the generated migration file ignores the current state of the database, and the generated SQL script creates all the tables as if there were nothing in the database.

I've searched all over the web, but I haven't found any similar cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that either your persistence unit is incorrectly configured, or you are comparing the model with the wrong database.

1. Check if the entities you want to generate scripts for are included in the persistence unit. Configuration of the persistence unit: https://jpa-buddy.com/documentation/database-versioning/#using-a-data-model
2. Also, make sure your database connection is correctly set up (for example, specifying the schema explicitly if you're using a non-default one). Connecting to a non-default schema: https://jpa-buddy.com/documentation/database-connections/#postgresql
3. After that, ensure that you have selected the correct persistence unit and database connection during script generation

[image: diff]

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact, my problem stemmed from the fact that my schema was not the default one. I had to add in the connection params ?currentSchema=historization section, as the documentation indicates: https://jpa-buddy.com/documentation/database-connections/#postgresql

The only thing that surprises me is that during the initial migration, I didn't get any error relating to the fact that my schema wasn't the standard one and that it was still able to execute the migration correctly.